# Update cloudwatch log group using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-aws-modules

i am having issues updating existing aws cloudwatch log group which were created manually using console. I am using data source to pull the information of the cloudwatch log groups and trying to update the retention period. But getting following error

```
data "aws_cloudwatch_log_groups" "integration_logs" {
log_group_name_prefix = "/aws/rds/instance/product"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "intergration_logs" {
name              = data.aws_cloudwatch_log_groups.integration_logs.log_group_names
retention_in_days = "731"

}
```

Error

```
 resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "intergration_logs":
 494:   name              = data.aws_cloudwatch_log_groups.integration_logs.log_group_names
├────────────────
│ data.aws_cloudwatch_log_groups.integration_logs.log_group_names is set of string with 4 
elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.
```

We have 4 log groups, so its bringing the correct information, but i am not sure what i am missing here

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve an existing log group and then modify it? If so, you need to directly manage it with Terraform config and import it into your state instead. That would fix this problem and avoid others as well.

Comment: hi yes, the resource was created manually and not through terraform, thats why when i joined i now have to update the log group using terraform, this log group has data in it and we cannnot delete this log group. I was thinking if there is a way to update it using terraform through data source

Comment: If you cannot delete it, then you need to do what I commented, and not what you are trying to do in the question.